# Changing the child element's color but only when hovering specific parent element (all parents have the same class)

Tags: jquery

I'm using the ".nav_item" items and each one of them has couple of paragraphs inside. Now, what I'm trying to do is to change the first paragraph's color (.nav_item p:first-child) by adding/removing CSS class on hovering the ".nav_item" (not the paragraph itself).

```
$('.nav_item').hover(
       function(){ 
          $('.nav_item p:first-child').addClass('hover')
    },
       function(){ 
          $('.nav_item p:first-child').removeClass('hover') 
    }
)
```

My code works great but the problem is that I want this change to happen only inside the ".nav_item" which I'm currently hovering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use CSS:

```css
.nav_item:hover p:first-child {
    /* add styles here */
}
```

jQuery is absolutely, 100% the WRONG tool for this job.

Comment: IE is doing weird stuff with first-child, depends if older browsers must be supported or not

Comment: @Frederik.L As I always say, if people are going out of their way to disable Windows Update and making our lives difficult, sod 'em. Besides, a feature like this is eye-candy at best and therefore completely optional ;)

Comment: Niet, thank you so much (I don't know what I was thinking.)! P.S. Older browsers are not important for this project so this solution will do just fine. :)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol agreed for "eye-candy" :P

Comment: **100% the WRONG tool for this job.**
Golden words! If I could, I'd upvote this post twice!